# how to keep bootstrap form button inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I put this button in a form it starts a new line but I want it to say inline. I tried adding class="form-inline" but it doesn't work. I must be bad at searching online because I can't find the right answer myself.

What is the bootstrap convention to keep it inline?

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="inline btn btn-info btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>
                <button class="form-inline glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-xs btn-danger del" type="button"></button>                 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sv1gaaa/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just alter your markup a little:

Like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oqw7vsag/1/)

```
<td> 
    <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-xs btn-danger del" type="button"></button>
    </form>
</td>
```